# Entity Registration module: Enable registration by default or programmatically

Tags: 7

By default, the [Entity Registration](https://www.drupal.org/project/registration) module disables the registration. We need to enable it everytime a node is created from 'Manage Registrations - Settings' tab. How to automate the process?

I tried changing the 'status' value to '1' in registration_field_info() of registration.field.inc but it didn't work.

Is there a way to do it programmatically, otherwise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/**
* Implements hook_entity_insert().
*/
function registration_entity_insert($entity, $entity_type) {
  $registration_type = registration_get_entity_registration_type($entity_type, $entity);
  if ($registration_type !== FALSE) {
list($entity_id) = entity_extract_ids($entity_type, $entity);

$settings2 = array(
  'multiple_registrations' => 0,
  'from address' => variable_get('site_mail', ini_get('sendmail_from')),
);

$settings = array(
  'status' => 1,
  'capacity' => 0,
  'send_reminder' => 0,
  'settings' => serialize($settings2),
);

registration_update_entity_settings($entity_type, $entity_id, $settings);
//registration_entity_set_default_settings($entity_type, $entity);
 }
}
```

References:

http://drupal.org/node/1430870

http://drupal.org/node/1357280